# Set Checkmark on view did appear using will display cell not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

Here is my code for the WillDisplayRow function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let monetaryCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: [1,0])

    //configure you cell here.
    if AppState.sharedInstance.filterPaymentMonetaryIsOn {
        monetaryCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        return monetaryCell!
    } else {
        monetaryCell?.accessoryType = .none
        return monetaryCell!
    }
}
```

And in my DidSelectRow:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let monetaryCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: [1,0])
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath == [0,0] {
        print(indexPath)
    } else if indexPath == [1,0] {
        if AppState.sharedInstance.filterPaymentMonetaryIsOn == true {
            monetaryCell!.accessoryType = .none
            AppState.sharedInstance.filterPaymentMonetaryIsOn = false
        } else {
            monetaryCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            AppState.sharedInstance.filterPaymentMonetaryIsOn = true
        }
```

Can someone help me out as to why this isnt working? Also, I have alot more cells and when selected each one has the same properties as above. What I'm looking for is the checkmark to be displayed when I reload the view or close and reopen the view. I hope this makes sense. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I looked for a few hours but couldn't find a similar situation.

Thank you in advance.

Denis Angell

Comment: I think you would have been implementing this for multiple cells right? Then why there is sharedInstance used? It's singleton instance which won't be suitable for multiple cell's case!

Comment: Why is it not suitable?

Comment: Because if you doing a checkmark for suppose cell 2nd, Then if there are 5 cells. It will consider checkmark True condition for all 5 cells and mark checkmark to all 5 cells. You will face a logical issue. Actually you've to handle a boolean individually for each cell's index.

Comment: And thats exactly what I've done

Comment: No @Denis, by checking your cellforrowatindex, I can clearly see, you are not using indexpath.row to grab any boolean or model to verify checkmark should be kept there for particular cell or not. Please check it, you will able to do it.

Comment: Oh I thought you were referring to didSelectRowAt... So how do I properly achieve this if I need to specify each row?

Answer (score 0):

Move your check mark display functionality from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to `willDisplayCell` method of `UITableViewDelegate`. `willDisplayCell` method works in such a way that whenever the cell about to appear on screen `willDisplayCell` method calls and desired functionality executes as expected.